# Authorization Bearer token is replaced by Basic token on mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, axios

I have a strange problem, connected with using interceptors to send Bearer token

```
const $api = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: API_URL,
})

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
if (config && config.headers && localStorage.getItem('token')){
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `bearer 
${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
}
return config
})
```

Here is my code to add Bearer token to every requests. So, if i use it from Laptop browser, everything is ok, but if i am using mobile browser, token is changing to basic.
It is a request from PC:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWfFk.png)

Same request recorded by Proxyman (I am using xcode simulator to represent mobile behavior)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmXGe.png)

Axios Version
1.5.0

Browser
Chrome, Safari

Additional Library Versions
"react": "18.2.0",

Check every solutions, but nothing works